# How can I tell if an egg has gone bad without cracking it open?

Tags: food

Like anyone on the planet, I hate the smell of rotten eggs. How can I tell if an egg is bad without cracking it open?

So far all I have tried is simply cracking it open and then throwing away the egg if it is bad, but that creates a bad smell and is a waste - I might be able to use some for cooking that I would otherwise throw away.

Comment: In regards to the edit: getting help on *what* to try would be where you would ask on [Cooking.SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/), getting help on something *else* to try would be where you would ask here.

Comment: ... still seems like a scope issue. one of the "off chance cases" where listing what has been tried is difficult, yet the question is still valid.

Comment: That rant is not apropriate

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I place the egg in a glass of water.

If it floats, it is bad. If it stands up, use it for cooking (e.g. a hard boiled egg but not soft), it's getting old. If it sinks, you're safe.

Why?

> The outer shell of an egg has two membranes under it. When an egg is laid, it is warm and starts cooling which contracts the inner part of the egg more than the shell and pulls the two membranes apart. As a result, air gets trapped in between the membranes (there is not enough air initially for it to float).

<sup>[Source](http://awesci.com/why-do-bad-eggs-float/)</sup>

As this egg gets older, air is taken in (due to slightly higher pressure from the contractions) through pores in the egg. Eventually, bacteria will get in too. When the egg has enough air to float, it's probably gone bad with the bacteria.

[image: 4 egg positions]

*Image © Tim, 2014*

Comment: I put my egg in some cold water and it came up as 'cooking'!

Comment: You can also use that for hard boiling, but I'd advise not soft!

Comment: If this is your image, that's really cool that you made it up for this answer. If not, some attribution would be nice :)

Comment: +1 for the illustration of wrong! A of answer too, I guess!

Comment: I raise chickens - just a note on this technique - if you wash your farm-fresh, previously unwashed eggs, they must immediately go in the fridge, since you're washing away the outermost layer of what was once mucous... so the eggs start to dry out quicker and *puf* go bad. Otherwise they're good on the counter for a couple of weeks!

Comment: Isn't that "wrong" just a poached egg?

Comment: @Tim I thought it was supposed to represent a pot of boiling water due to the "cooking".

Comment: I also use this technique but the explanation does not make sense: basically it says that the mass increases (with air coming in) and that makes it float! It's actually the opposite: gas and water leave the egg, which reduces the mass and makes it float (c.f. Archimedes). I also found a more detailed explanation in a comment here: http://whatscookingamerica.net/Eggs/EggsFloat.htm

Comment: @DidierL do you have a reference? Because losing something *lighter* than water gives it a higher density and will sink...?

Comment: @DidierL read that... I'm quoting here *The tilting is caused by air pockets in the eggs that **increase** in size over time*.

Comment: I was referring to the comment at the bottom of that page (unfortunately they didn't update the page itself after the comment).

Comment: @DidierL he is wrong... It's not about weight it is about density, and to float the density has to be lower than 1. *It does not make a difference if there is more or less air in the egg.* is nonsense. Go fill a ping pong ball with a metal... It will sink.

Comment: Density = weight / volume. The volume of the egg is constant so it does not really make a difference to talk about one or the other. If you want to reduce density, you _have_ to reduce the weight. This can only be done if something _leaves_ the egg. I think water leaves the egg, and is replaced by air or gas, which are lighter.

Comment: +1 in general, but most certainly for the "wrong" - funny unnecessary image is unnecessarily funny

Answer (score 10):

If you are in a situation where bringing water adds another burden to you, you can identify the quality of an egg by gently shaking it and hearing it. This works like a charm in me.

It states in the [Source:](http://www.thekitchn.com/quick-tip-how-to-tell-if-eggs-are-still-good-176466)

> Take an egg from the refrigerator and hold it up to your ear. Shake it gently. If it's fresh, it won't make a sound. If it's on the older side, the egg will make a slight rattle.

But according to [this source](http://www.discusscooking.com/forums/f22/how-to-check-if-an-egg-is-rotten-30950.html) there is a warning here

> Shaking an egg next to your ear to see (or rather hear) if it's rotten works without fail for me. Eggs that have gone bad make the characteristic sound of something splashing around inside the shell while fresh eggs make no sound at all.
>
> For those not used to this method of detection, a word of caution
>   might be in order. Do not hold the egg too tightly or shake too
>   energetically. It is not that in case you do so you will fail to
>   detect a rotten egg. Detection will be as easy or even easier in this
>   case. However, there may be undesirable side effects.

Answer (score 8):

[Source](http://www.listotic.com/36-genius-kitchen-tips-and-tricks/4/)

Through this method, the approximate age of the eggs can be found. So We can be able to know how long can we keep and which egg to use first.

[image]